# Efficiently syncing data between Children and Parents in React

Tags: reactjs

I have an API call, which requires a dictionary of 200 key-value pairs. I would like to split this call into multiple smaller calls, which might reuse some of the data. E.g. 30 calls, using 10 key-values each.

In order to do that, I created one single parent component, let's assume its called `Form`. Additionally, I will create smaller forms, which pass some of the data to the `Form` component. If for some such smaller form the data already exists in the `Form` component, I would like to pre-fill it.

So in this example, `Form` is split into 30 smaller forms/steps, which are synced with `Form`.

The main problem is the these Children are not direct children. Since I'm using Material UI, the form elements e.g. buttons are children of UI elements e.g. Grids. What is the easiest way to sync data between Children (form elements) and Parents (Form) in such a way.

Currently, if a child component inside of another child component, I use 2 callbacks to pass data upstream, however that doesn't seem efficient. Is there any other way?

Comment: Check out Redux for storing global state that any component in your app can connect to and read data from: https://redux.js.org/

Comment: React works best when you have a unidirectional data flow (parent passes data to child, child informs parent something changed). You could use context as a way achieving this, by storing the data + some functions in a context provider and having consumers of the context invoke those functions to indicate something changed. Redux seems like a heavy-handed use-case if this is your only case of needing this - Redux is best reserved for truly global data

Comment: You could also try [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) for smaller use cases.